# concatenation - 2 lists

Tags: haskell, concatenation

I need some help :/

I have the fowlling list:

```
xs = [("a",1,[(11,"aa","aa"),(22,"bb","bb")]),("b",2,[(33,"cc","cc"),(44,"dd","dd")])]
```

And I need to make a function that allows me to change the values of "a" and 1 (the first 2 values from the first 3-tuple on the list).

I tried to solve this by spliting my list:

```
xs1 = ("a",1,[(11,"aa","aa"),(22,"bb","bb")])
xs2 = ("b",2,[(33,"cc","cc"),(44,"dd","dd")])
```

then:

```
changeXs (_, _, z) x y = (x,y,z)
newXs x y = [changeXs xs1 x y]
```

this works for change xs1. I thought that now it would be easy concatenate xs2 to my newXs function, using ++ ... But it wont work (I believe I cant use ++ whit pattern matching, am I right?)

Any ideas about how can I concatenate xs2 to my newXs function ? Or any other approach to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert_new_xy x y ((_, _, z) : rest) = (x, y, z) : rest
```

Test:

```
*Main> insert_new_xy "foo" 42 xs
[("foo",42,[(11,"aa","aa"),(22,"bb","bb")]),("b",2,[(33,"cc","cc"),(44,"dd","dd")])]
```

The `((_, _, z) : rest)` pattern matches a list, whose head is a three-element tuple and binds last element in that tuple and the tail of the list. Then it's just a matter of recombining the list, by creating a new tuple with given `x`, `y` and extracted `z`, and prepending it to the tail.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `++`.

`++` has the type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`
In other words, it takes two lists and "puts them together"
What you want is to add some `a` to a `[a]`

Try
`(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate `newXs x y`, that is a `list`, with `xs2`, that is a `tuple`.

Comment: Nomics already knows he can't do it (he even said so in his question); a useful answer would suggest something he *can* do.

Comment: Actually, one of Nomics questions was "But it wont work (I believe I cant use ++ whit pattern matching, am I right?)". Well, my answer is that, no, he's not right, (++) does not work not because of pattern matching, but because type mismatch between list and tuple. I think mine is a legitimate answer.